# Rspec presence: true check fails even though it works as intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following Rspec test with the following output for my User model in a Rails API I'm building:

```rb
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:michael) { User.new(email: "michael@email.com", password: "Password1", password_confirmation: "Password1") }

    it 'is not valid without a password' do
      michael.password = ''
      expect(michael).not_to be_valid, "Expect User to have a Password"
    end

  end
```

```sh
  1) User basic checks is not valid without a password
     Failure/Error: expect(michael).not_to be_valid, "Expect User to have a Password"
       Expect User to have a Password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

However, for some reason this test just fails, even with the following on my User model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :password,
            format: { with: /\A(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}\Z/, message: "Password must be at least 8 characters long, contain at least 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letter and 1 number" },
            confirmation: true,
            on: :create
end
```

The above validation works fine, as you can see here:

```sh
➜ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 2774
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.1)
irb(main):001:0> new = User.new
irb(main):002:0> new.email = "testing@testing.com"
irb(main):003:0> new.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "testing@testing.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
irb(main):004:0> new.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f743848dfb0 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "testing@testing.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: false>, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank", "can't be blank", "Password must be at least 8 characters long, contain at least 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase letter and 1 number"]}, @details={:password=>[{:error=>:blank}, {:error=>:blank}, {:error=>:invalid, :value=>nil}]}>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here for this test to fail? It's a painfully simple one, and all the other ones work as expected except for the password test.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your tests `password = ''` is a valid one because for Ruby, `''` is something. You have to add this to your validation:
`validates :password, presence: true, allow_blank: false`

Also, take a look, your password validation is for `on: :create` and in your spec you are not creating it.

Comment: Bad answer. `presence: true` validates attribute using `blank?` method. So the model valid if this attribute is not empty and not `nil`. You don't need to write `allow_blank: false`. And `on: :create` validation will called for new object if you use `valid?` method, even don't use `save` or `create` methods